# Mysql not restarting in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to connect my java program in the host OS with the mysql database in the ubuntu VM. I have created the necessary tables in the database and changed the bind-address in the `my.cnf` file to that of the host OS address. While I am trying to restart mysql, I am getting:

```
mysql stop/waiting
start: Job failed to start.
```

Then when I am trying to access mysql, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow below step to start MySQL server.

- Try to restart MySQL server from terminal. (In RHEL that is `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`)

Still same issue then follow below step.

- Rename `mysql.sock` file with another name e.g. `mysl.sock_old` in following directory.

  `/var/run/mysqld/`

Now restart your MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with mysql on Ubuntu14.04.
I fixed the issue by commenting configuration in /etc/mysql/my.cnf  file.

> innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
>
> innodb_log_file_size=54M

After commenting mysql service runs well..

Note :- If you comment these configuration then default configuration will take care the size of buffer pool and log file.
So not any issue .
But if you want to mention it manually , then provide 80% of your physical memory to buffer pool size.
and 25% of buffer pool size to log file.